# Generate random different string

Tags: c#

I want to generate a different random string every time I use the function.

```
public static Dictionary<string, long> Giftcodes = new Dictionary<string, long>();

private static Random random = new Random();

        public static string GenerateCode()
        {
            string code = "";

            string chars = "abcefhijkmnorsuvwxyzABCDEFHIKMNORSUVWXYZ1234567890";

            if (Giftcodes.Keys == null)
            {
                code = new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 16)
                    .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
            }else
            {
                while (!Giftcodes.Keys.Contains(code))
                {
                    code = new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 16)
                        .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
                }
            }

            return code;
        }
```

I did a little bit of researches but I found nothing.

Comment: What's the question you have?

Answer (score 1):

`while (!Giftcodes.Keys.Contains(code))` looks very suspicious, basically it does the opposite - it will generate a code until it is present in the dictionary, try changing it to:

```
do
{
    code = ....
} 
while (Giftcodes.ContainsKey(code));

// ...

Giftcodes.Add(code, 0); // do not forget to add the code
return code;
```

Also:

- Consider using [`Random.Shared`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.shared?view=net-7.0).
- Consider using [`HashSet<string>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-7.0) instead of dictionary if you don't need values
- Maybe you will need [Thread-safe collections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/) if this is used in multithreaded environment.

Comment: It gives me "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'" at the this line of code "while (Giftcodes.ContainsKey(code))".

Comment: @SecuritySupport [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

Comment: this is error that appears when I try to run the code.